# Can we use Google's Fused Location services in offline mode?

Tags: android, google-api, gps

I am planning to change my old location service to google's fused location services. My concern is to get get a googleapiclient I need to register using my api key, which requires a web call to google server.

This would restrict my apps function to internet availability. My understanding is there is no need have a internet dependency for location updates, as everything is a local affair. I can get the location from my gps and then save it in my shared preferences, then why to have an unnecessary dependency on network.

Am i missing something ? Please help.

thanks.

Comment: Just to add one more word - it would be pointless if it didn't work offline, right? Since the main goal of google fused location is to FUSE all the available sources of location and get the best possible location that there is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you are missing something - you don't need any api key to register `GoogleApiClient`:

```
googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getApplicationContext(), this, this).addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
googleApiClient.connect();
```

And yes, it does work in offline.